# How to permanently increase runtime/memory of a Firebase Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions via Firebase and was running into the default one-minute timeout and seeing `Function execution took 60000 ms, finished with status: 'error'` in my logs.

I found I could modify my runtime/memory from `60s/256mb` to `500s/512mb` at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/, but the next time I ran `firebase deploy --only functions`, it set them back to the original `60s/256mb` values.

Is there any way I can modify my code so the deployed function has different runtime/memory defaults? Right now, I'm exporting my function like so:

```js
export const myfunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("*/5 * * * *")
    .timeZone("UTC")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      await main();
    });
```

I'm currently on v1 version of functions, and am not running locally

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=1st#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation_2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `runWith()` as follows:

```
export const myfunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("*/5 * * * *")
    .runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 500,
      memory: "512MB",
    })
    .timeZone("UTC")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      await main();
    });
```

The corresponding doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=1st#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation_2).

Comment: Looks like it's only available on v2 - `TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule(...).runWith is not a function`. Even on v2, I get `TypeError: onSchedule(...).runWith is not a function`

Comment: No it is available in v1 as well. The syntax in my answer is V1 syntax. V2 syntax is different see the doc I refer to in my answer. You may add your entire `index.js` file to your question in order to check you correctly declared/configured your v1 CF.

Comment: Hi @Dr-Bracket, did you have time to check, following my last comment?

Comment: I couldn't get it working with v1, so I migrated to v2 and used

```javascript
export const combineAfDatav2 = onSchedule(
    {
      schedule: "*/5 3 * * *",
      timeoutSeconds: 500,
      memory: "2GiB",
      timeZone: "UTC",
    }, async (context) => {
      await main();
    });
```